# Redirect xterm to a background for a headless machine

Tags: bash, ubuntu, xterm

I have a application that launches xterm and dumps uart logs. I am able to see it launch and dump the logs in the GUI. However, Using a remote session I want the xterm output to be running as a background process somewhere so that I can switch back and forth within a single terminal.

Using GUI

[image]

Using remote terminal (SSH)

```
$ xterm
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

I tried to do something like, but failed to work -

```
alias xterm="/bin/bash -c"
```

I don't want to have `X forwarding` and launch a window on my local machine as well.

Comment: run a X server in the background - vnc server and connect with vnc client.

Comment: thanks.. but this is for automation, I want it to be available on the command line

Comment: Do you control (can you modify) the application that starts `xterm`?

Comment: `I want it to be available on the command line` then do you need `xterm`? Logs are just text. What application is that? What does the application do? How does it launches `xterm`? What is displayed in xterm? That `trying 127.0.0.1` looks liek a telnet session - is it telnet? Why not tell us? And, is it jtag debugger?

Comment: Really have a look into `screen`, as @jurez suggests. You can give each screen session a name (`-S? ) and recall(`-r`) it from any other shell on your system. So instead of xterm, let your program open a screen instead. Do not detour via X.

Answer (score 7):

If you just need the logs, you most likely don't need an X server or `xterm`.

You can simply run the target command itself. From your screenshot it looks like the command might be `telnet 127.0.0.1 <port_number>`. You can find it from the script that your application launches, or with `ps -ef` when it's running. If it's an UART, then you can also use `minicom` or `socat` to connect directly to serial port without any extra programs. This way, you don't even need `telnet`.

You can combine this command with either `screen` or `tmux` so that it's running in the background and you can switch to it from any terminal or console. Just run `screen` with no arguments, then run the command on virtual screen. Detach with `CTRL-a d`, and your command will continue to run in the background ready for you to reconnect to it at any time with `screen -r`.

Moreover, `screen` can also connect to serial port directly so you get two for the price of one.

The thing with `xterm` is that it will not write the logs anywhere except in the graphics buffer, and even there it will be only as flashing pixels which is not suitable for any processing. If you insist on going that way, you have several options:

- Change the script that application runs (might not be possible depending on your situation)
- Replace `/usr/bin/xterm` with your dummy script that just runs `bash` instead of `xterm`, and redirects the output to a file (ugly, but you could probably avoid breaking other applications by changing `PATH` and putting it somewhere else). In your script, you can use `bash`'s redirection features such as `>`, or pipe output to `tee`.
- Start a VNC server in the background and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable when you run your application to the number of virtual screen. In this case, any windows from application will open on VNC virtual screen and you can connect to it as you please.
- Use `xvfb` as a dummy X server and combine it with xterm logging, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Fake xterm on X11-less systems**
You can also create a wrapper script that replaces xterm with another function. Test this out on a laptop with X11:

```sh
$ function xterm {
echo "hello $@"
}
$ xterm world 1
hello world 1
$ export -f xterm
$ /bin/xterm          # opens a new xterm session
$ xterm world 2       # commands executed in second terminal
hello world 2
```

This means that you've replaced the command `xterm` for a function in all of the child processes.

Now, if you already know that your script will work in a terminal without xterm, you could create a function that accepts all of the parameters and executes it. No need for complicated screen stuff or replacing /usr/bin/xterm.

**Solution 2: Dump UART data for the winz**
If you want to save all of the uart data into a file, this is easily fixed by creating a screen session and a log file. Below the command will create a session named `myscreensessionname` that listens on the serial connection `/dev/ttyUSB0` and writes its data to `/home/$USER/myscreensessionname.log`.

```sh
$ screen -dmS myscreensessionname -L -Logfile /home/$USER \
/myscreensessionname.log /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
```

Note that if you're going to use multiple screen sessions, you might want to use serial ids instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0`. You can identify the connections with `udevadmin` as follows.

```sh
$  udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 | grep 'by-id'
S: serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_FTBDBIQ7-if00-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_FTBDBIQ7-if00-port0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4.4.4.1:1.0-port0
```

Here, instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0`, I would make use of `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_TTL232R-3V3_FTBDBIQ7-if00-port0`.

EDIT:
You can attach the screen session with the following command. Once in the screen session, press `crtl+a`, and press `d` to detach.

```sh
$ screen -Dr myscreensessionname
```

To view all of your screen sessions:

```sh
$ screen -list
There is a screen on:
        2382.myscreensessionname        (04/02/2021 10:32:07 PM)        (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-user.
```